# Dynamic prioritization in list with blanks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of priorities in Column A. The list also has blanks:

```
A1: Headline
A2: 3
A3: 1
A4: "Blank"
A5: 4
A6: "Blank"
A7: 2
```

When a user changes a priority, say A5 is changed to 1, the A2 should be changed to 4, A3 to 2 and A7 to 3, and the blanks should stay blank.

I can't get the blanks to stay blank!. I am using the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myVal As Variant
    Dim iCount As Long

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim myRange As Range

    Set myRange = Range("A2:A200")

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A200")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    myVal = Target.Value
    iCount = 1
    For Each cell In myRange
        If Intersect(Target, cell) Is Nothing Then
            If iCount = myVal Then
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
            cell.Value = iCount
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
    Next cell


    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Have been trying to find solution for 2 days now - I am stuck - anyone - Help!!

The dynamic update fills out the blanks with a priority

[image]

Comment: Seems like there are more scenarios than that one example? Are you only trying to fix that one case?

Comment: @TimWilliams Nope - trying to fix more things

I would have uploaded an example but can't seem to find out how that is done.

There are 4 user stories (change options) that need to be solved:

1) A user changes the priority on existing task with a priority to a different priority and the priorities dynamically change based on that
2) A user adds a priority to a "blank" and the priorities change based on that
3) A user marks a priority as "done" and the priority is set to "blank" and the the priorities cane based on that
4) A user adds a priority to a blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assume that column A contains priority as non-repeating, uninterrupted consecutive integers.
- Please provide additional details about the logic if the output doesn't align with your expected result.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim sTarget
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim arr(), aData, i As Long, iSign As Integer
    Dim myRange As Range, bAdvance As Boolean
    Dim iStart As Integer, iEnd As Integer
    Set myRange = Range("A2:A200")
    With Target
        If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A200")) Is Nothing Or _
            .CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        aData = myRange.Value
        ReDim arr(1 To UBound(aData))
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            If Len(aData(i, 1)) > 0 And i + 1 <> .Row Then
                arr(aData(i, 1)) = "A" & i + 1
            End If
        Next
        If .Value > sTarget Then
            iStart = sTarget + 1: iEnd = .Value: iSign = -1
        Else
            iStart = .Value: iEnd = sTarget - 1: iSign = 1
        End If
        For i = iStart To iEnd
            Range(arr(i)) = i + iSign
        Next
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A200")) Is Nothing) And _
        Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then sTarget = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update:

> OP update the logic with comment

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim vOld
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim arr(), aData, i As Long, iShift As Integer
    Dim iStart As Integer, iEnd As Integer, vNew
    Dim myRange As Range
    Const LASTROW As Integer = 200
    Set myRange = Range("A1:A" & LASTROW)
    ' Validate sigle cell change and within the data range
    If Intersect(Target, myRange) Is Nothing Or _
        Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    vNew = Target.Value
    ' No change
    If vNew = vOld Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    aData = myRange.Value
    ReDim arr(1 To UBound(aData))
    ' Store priority and cell refer in an array
    For i = 2 To UBound(aData)
        If Len(aData(i, 1)) > 0 And i <> Target.Row Then
            arr(aData(i, 1)) = "A" & i
        End If
    Next
    ' Blank to number, or number to blank
    If vOld = "" Then vOld = LASTROW + 1
    If vNew = "" Then vNew = LASTROW + 1
    If vNew > vOld Then
        iStart = vOld + 1: iEnd = vNew: iShift = -1
    Else
        iStart = vNew: iEnd = vOld - 1: iShift = 1
    End If
    ' Update prority
    For i = iStart To iEnd
        If arr(i) = "" Then Exit For
        Range(arr(i)) = i + iShift
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
' Get the value before change
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A200")) Is Nothing) And _
        Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        vOld = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! - It works like a charm when changing existing priorities but II think I was too unclear in the description - my bad and apologies. I have tried to specify a bit further. Am trying to find a way to upload an excel file with the examples - how do I do that?

Comment: I have added an image with the change descriptions - hope that explains it a bit more in detail - and many-many thanks for even looking at this

Comment: I'm afraid there is a typo in column `Chang4`. Priority `4` is missing.

Comment: Thanks a lot - damn I was far from the taget! - You are a superhero